# Register position of click in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I am trying to make an error message pop up on a wpf page if a user clicks(with touch) the page and make it appear where they clicked the page.  The reason behind it is I am trying to teach them how to register a swipe without accidentally clicking.

I thought about putting buttons all over the screen but knew that would be tedious and not perfectly accurate.  I thought of registering the TouchPoint(s) with a TouchDown event on a canvas but that would register my error message with touching down for a swipe as well.

Any suggestions of how I could make a TextBox pop up at the position someone clicks a screen?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you determining that they did a swipe?  Presumably by listening to TouchDown and TouchUp then checking how far the user has moved between those?  If so, then just re-use that same logic except reverse it.

Comment: I'm not currently determining if a swipe is registered.  I'm creating a tutorial application that teaches people how to do different interactions on a new touchscreen technology.  I think what I'll do is register the points of TouchDown and TouchUp and if they are in a very close proximity (which I will try to match to the same proximity that the touchscreen uses) I can register it as a click and pop up my error message.  Otherwise it's a swipe and all will be well. @RobertLevy

Comment: well you wont be teaching them correctly if you are using a different set of thresholds than whatever you are trying to teach them to use... kinda defeats the purpose of your project, doesn't it?